# Problems with global variable in inner OnItemClickListener class

Tags: java, android

I have an android fragment, that has a listview. for that listview I implemented an inner OnItemClickListener class.
When there's a click, I save the selection in a global variable called SelectedIndex.

If I click again on that list, I can see the previous selection correctly, So its saving the state on the global variable correctly.

The problem is when I try to access to that same global variable from another inner class, for example, one class used for listen to clicks on a button. Is always showing the  value I used for initialize the varialbe (-1).

The code of the fragment:

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing the view for the recentCalls list
 */
public class RecentCallsFragment extends Fragment {

    private Cursor cursorAllRows;
    private RecentCallsTable rcTable;
    private ListView list;
    private RecentCallsAdapter adapter;
    Button btnDelete, btnCreditRequest, btnCreditBlock, btnSendTo;
    int selectedIndex; //this is the global variable that I am using.

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rcTable = new RecentCallsTable(getActivity());
        cursorAllRows = rcTable.getRecentCallsCursor();
        adapter = new RecentCallsAdapter(getActivity(), cursorAllRows);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);

        btnDelete = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        btnCreditRequest = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonCr);
        btnCreditBlock = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonCRD);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickHandler()); //Add the inner ItemClickLister

        btnSendTo = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonSendTo);
        btnSendTo.setOnClickListener(new DebugOnClick());//here I add the inner clicklister

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Class that handles the one click action on the list
     */
    public class ItemClickHandler implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

        //when there's one fast click, keep the selection on the item or remove it if already has it
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            int prevSelection = adapter.getSelectedIndex();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Integer.toString(selectedIndex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int newSelection = position;
            if(prevSelection == position){
                newSelection = -1;
            }
            selectedIndex = newSelection; //here I change the value of the global variable
            adapter.setSelectedIndex(newSelection);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class DebugOnClick implements View.OnClickListener{

        public DebugOnClick(){
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Integer.toString(selectedIndex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //here I show the value of the global variable and is always -1
        }
    }
}
```

Which may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. The buttons are in the main activity, so I just moved the global variable to the main Activity and started to manipulate it from the fragments like this:

```
MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
ma.rcSelected = newSelection;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility that comes into my mind. When you have an inner class instantiated it implicitly binds with an instance of the hosting class (as if it were a reference of the hosting class). So I assume that the inner classes that you use are each linked with a different instance of the hosted class and thus using a different selectedIndex. Your global variable is not really global, its an instance variable.

Comment: So what can be the solution? Move the inner classes to indepent classes? I was thinking about this, but I dont know how to implement this with listeners.

Comment: I don't see any problem with externalising those inner classes, a listener doesn't have to be anonymous or defined as inner class. When creating the listener you should provide the link to the correct RecentCallsFragment in the constructor that they should share.